# Reconstructing Document in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb, document, database, nosql

I am attempting to make a database to keep a simple menu of items for my favorite restaurants. I have a class for establishments, a class for different menus (like happy hour/dinner/lunch/etc.) and a class for individual items on the menus. Each establishment class has a set of menus and each menu has a set of items.

Is there a single command to reconstruct an entire restaurants menu into a single document?

I'm guessing it has something to do with functions. I have tried messing around with `unwind`, `expand`, `out`, and `traverse` but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried "fetch plans" in Orientdb.
https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Fetching-Strategies.html

Giving -1 as the depth level will go through the links unlimited and load all the documents to a single doc.

In your case the fetch plan would be something like this.

```
"select from Establishment fetchPlan *:-1"
```

Comment: I think you're on track. Fetch plans looks like the way to go. I tried:

     select * from Establishment fetchplan *:-1

and am still getting the Establishment result by it self. Are fetch plans supposed to work for linksets?

Comment: `----+-----+-------------+---------------+-----
#   |@RID |@CLASS       |name           |menus
----+-----+-------------+---------------+-----
0   |#11:1|Establishment|Cool River Cafe|[1]  
`

There is the output

Comment: yes it works on linksets. Have you tried executing this query on the orientdb studio (web interface). Because from the console it displays the results like that (i.e. menus as [1])